# How do I install Flash plugin for Firefox in Slackware 14.1?

Tags: firefox, slackware, plugin

I searched on Google but the tutorials I found said they had to paste the plugin in `/usr/lib/firefox/plugins`
But this folder does not exist!

Comment: where did you find this tutorial? Any link?

Comment: Yes, any link. But I will not post here because it is in Portuguese (I'm Brazilian) and would not help much!

Comment: I'd still paste it, we can use google translate to try and at least partially follow. I do it all the time!

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit system? If so, you're looking for the folder `/usr/lib64/firefox/plugins` rather than `/usr/lib/firefox/plugins`.

Comment: If it turns out you're on a 32-bit system, could you post the output of `ls /usr/lib/firefox*` ?

Comment: There is a folder like this: /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins
I put the plugin in that folder, but the youtube videos carry a few seconds and then close a message asking me to download the flahs appear as if I did not have the plugin, but when I type about: plugins in firefox it recognizes the flash exists and is enabled!

Comment: # ls /usr/lib/firefox*
No such file or directory

Comment: On a 64-bit system, you'll probably find firefox and its associated directories with `ls /usr/lib64/firefox*`, though I'm not sure that'll help much.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Slackbuild: http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/multimedia/flashplayer-plugin/

You simply download the flash tarball: [32-bit](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.332/install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz) or [64-bit](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.332/install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz), as well as the SlackBuild: [flashplayer-plugin.tar.gz](http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.1/multimedia/flashplayer-plugin.tar.gz)

From wherever you downloaded them to:

```
# tar xzf flashplayer-plugin.tar.gz
# mv install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz flashplayer-plugin
# cd flashplayer-plugin
# ./flashplayer-plugin.SlackBuild
```

This will produce a package for you to install. At the end, it'll say something like

```
Slackware package /tmp/flashplayer-plugin-11.2.202.332-x86_64-1_SBo.tgz created.
```

Then just run

```
# installpkg /tmp/flashplayer-plugin-11.2.202.332-x86_64-1_SBo.tgz
```

That should take care of everything for you.

Comment: Your username never gets old 8-)

Comment: haha, thanks! also: woo! the upvote on this answer finally pushed me above 100 rep! :D

Comment: If you create accounts on other SE sites you get a 100rep bonus, so that'll get you to 200

Comment: Package flashplayer-plugin-11.2.202.332-x86_64-1_SBo.tgz installed.

I did it properly, but I still have problems, I can not watch a video from youtube to the end. The videos stop in the beginning and youtube says I need flash.

Comment: That sounds strange. Do the videos play even a little bit, or do you get the error message right away?

Comment: Either way, I'm not confident that I'll be able to help you much past this point except for suggesting that you try restarting your machine to see if that helps Firefox recognize the plugin better (I'm doubtful of this, but it's worth a try).

Comment: Videos play for a moment, and then the video and for the error message appears. This is strange because I'm sure the flash plugin is the latest version.

Comment: I already re-installed slackware but nothing changes and installed the flash plugin the way you taught but the problem persists.

Comment: Very odd. The last thing I can suggest is asking over at the official Slackware forums at: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/ The folks there are very helpful, and even the creator of Slackware, Patrick Volkerding, hangs out there and answers questions. Though I'm not sure that this is a Slackware specific issue, it sounds more like a flash or Firefox issue.

Comment: Then I'll see if I can find help on llinuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14
I also think that this problem is very strange flash, I tried using Konqueror and he showed the same mproblema trying to load youtube videos.
With firefox I tested the version of Flash that link: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/
The firefox showed that single flash plugin is out of date, but it is not out of date!
because when I type about: plugins in firefox, this result appears:

Comment: File: libflashplayer.so
     Path: / usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
     Version: 11,2,202,336
     State: Enabled
     Shockwave Flash 11.2 R202
And this is the latest version of flash.
Anyway thanks for your attention, and for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Download flash*tar.gz for correct architecture(x86/x64) from adobe website. Untar it like this:

```
tar xvf install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
```

Move libflashplayer.so to correct folder like this

```
cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/
```

*/lib/* for 32 bit. Restart your browser. Done!

Answer (score 0):

I know slackbuild-way is probably the proper way to do that. Although I have it working only for my user by copying the plugin to `~/.mozilla/plugins/`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had to go this link https://www.youtube.com/html5.
And I enabled HTML5.